# Regex for whole numbers only and not a blank string

Tags: regex

Please can you help me, I need a regex expressions to only allow whole numbers and the string cannot be blank.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching here?

Comment: Well, `४` is a number....

Answer (score 5):

```
/^-?\d+$/
```

This regex would match one or more digits. So won't allow blank as required, and would only allow whole numbers
Actually the `+` after `\d` imposes that at least one digit be present in the input string.
The `-` in the beginning checks for a `-`, and the following `?` makes it optional.

Comment: oops i forgot that. let me make an amendment to my answer

Comment: i have made changes to my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should try this one:

```
^\d+$
```

^  : begining of the string to capture
$  : end of the string to capture
\d : all the digits (equivalent to [0-9])
+  : at least one of the class